# How to append python list to each pandas dataframe cell containing a array?

Tags: python, pandas

**MY CODE:**

```
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=["a","b"], index=np.arange(1,3))
for col in df.columns:
  df[col].values[:]=[[]*2]
print(df)
for col,n in enumerate(df.columns):
  for row in range(1,3):
    df[n][row].append([1,2,3])
    print(df)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
           a   b
1  []  []
2  []  []
0 a
             a   b
1  [[1, 2, 3]]  []
2  [[1, 2, 3]]  []
0 a
                        a   b
1  [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]  []
2  [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]  []
1 b
                        a            b
1  [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]  [[1, 2, 3]]
2  [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]  [[1, 2, 3]]
1 b
                        a                       b
1  [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]  [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
2  [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]  [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

I want output as the list added to all the cells. But instead the list being added to a cell, it is being added to each row of the column. Please help. Thank you in advance.

**Suggested output:**

```
    a       b
1   []     []
2   []     []
0 a
         a    b
1   [[1,2,3]] []
2       []    []
0 a
         a    b
1   [[1,2,3]] []
2   [[1,2,3]] []
1 b
         a         b
1   [[1,2,3]]  [[1,2,3]]
2   [[1,2,3]]  []
1 b
         a         b
1   [[1,2,3]]  [[1,2,3]]
2   [[1,2,3]]  [[1,2,3]]
```

Comment: can you show the expected output

Comment: I have edited the question including suggested output. Please have a look. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, doing `[[] * 2]` doesn't actually produce `[[],[]]` as you probably expected, but `[[]]`. When you do `df[col].values[:] = [[]*2]` you are actually setting all rows in the column `col` to the same list. You can check this like so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["a","b"], index=np.arange(1,3))
df["a"].values[:] = [[] * 2]
df["a"][1].append([1,2,3])
print(df)
```

After doing above operation the `df` would become like below, since you are actually modifying both rows at once:

```
             a    b
1  [[1, 2, 3]]  NaN
2  [[1, 2, 3]]  NaN
```

---

What you want to do is this:

```
for col in df.columns:
    for row in df.index:
        df[col][row] = []
```

Then

```
for col in df.columns:
    for row in df.index:
        df[col][row].append([1,2,3])
        print(df)
```

(Also notice how I don't use `enumerate(df.columns)` because we don't need it, and replaced `range(1,3)` with `df.index`.)